# Jquery List Selection Variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, listview, jquery-mobile

I have this Jquery list element being used with a sample app I'm using to teach myself coding. I have various values being rendered onto the list just fine. The problem that lies is that I'm trying to find out what item on the list the user selected so I can then go back to the database and pull all the information relating to that item out onto the screen.

The method I've tried doing it so far is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){
        $("#list").empty();
        var url="http://localhost/test/login/json4.php";
        $.getJSON(url,function(json){
            //loop through deals
            $.each(json.deals,function(i,dat){
                $("#list").append("<li><a id='"+dat.dealid+"'><h1>"+dat.name+"</h1><p>"+dat.dname+"</p></a></li>");
                $(document).on('click', '#'+dat.dealid, function(event){  
                    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
                    {
                        listObject.itemID = $(this).attr('id'); 
                        $.mobile.changePage( "#index2", { transition: "slide"} );
                        event.handled = true;
                    }
                });            
            });
            $("#list").listview('refresh');
        });
    });

    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index2', function(){       
    $('#index2 [data-role="content"]').html('You have selected Link' + listObject.itemID);
     });

   var listObject = {
      itemID : null
   }    
</script>
```

A Json array is created of all the list items and is being rendered on the screen. What I've managed to do then is that when a user makes a selection it goes onto a new page (index 2) and in index 2 it says what database field id is associated with that item selected.

I've been trying the last couple of days to find a method whereby I can take that id number and bring it back over to the database side but I've been having no luck - it either breaks my original list when I add new code or just nothing happens!

If anybody can help me out I'd really appreciate it! It seems like a core lesson that most people in my position should learn so if anybody would like to teach where to do from here it would be fantastic!

Thanks in advance for the help! Have a nice weekend everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){
    $("#list").empty();
    var url="http://localhost/ce/json4.php";
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
        //loop through deals                
        $.each(json.deals,function(i,dat){
            $("#list").append("<li><a id='"+dat.dealid+"' data-restaurantid=" + dat.restaurantid + " data-image=" + dat.image + "><h1>"+dat.name+"</h1><h6>"+dat.dname+"</h6><h5>"+dat.description+"</h5></a></li>");
            $(document).on('click', '#'+dat.dealid, function(event){  
                if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
                {
                    dealObject.dealID = $(this).attr('id'); 
                    dealObject.dealName = $(this).find('h6').html();
                    dealObject.description = $(this).find('h5').html(); 

                    $.mobile.changePage( "offer.php", { transition: "slide"} );
                    event.handled = true;
                }
            });            
        });
        $("#list").listview('refresh');
    });
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index2', function(){       
    $('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('input#desc').val(dealObject.description);
    $('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('input#name').val(dealObject.dealName);
    $('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('input#did').val(dealObject.dealID);


});

var dealObject = {
    dealID : null,
    dealName : null,
    description: null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the localStorage to temporarily store the itemID, and retrive it in the next page.

```
localStorage['itemID'] = $(this).attr('id');
```

Then retrive it in the #index2:

```
itemID = localStorage['itemID'];
```

Comment: Hi @Siddharth Thanks for the comment back. The itemID is moving over to index2 just fine - I was hoping to find a way that I can send that variable to the PHP file like the one where I got my original data so I can inserted it into an SQL statement and render the information I need from the database. Could localstorage also be used for that?

Comment: Well, if the PHP file is in the exact same domain, yes, localStorage can be used for that... But it'll be much better to pass the variable to the PHP file using GET using this syntax: database.php?itemID=xxxx

Comment: and then, you can retrieve the value of itemID inside the PHP file using:   $itemID = $_REQUEST['itemID'];

Comment: Okay, you'll have to forgive me, I am very new to all of this so I haven't come across them terms yet! What should I go looking up to find the GET syntax and some examples?
I understand about the use of it in the PHP file I think cause I've used session variables already so it looks similar. Have you any idea where this would be incorporated in my code above too? 

Thanks!!!!